# Display Exceptions in SWT

Tags: java, exception, swt, jface

In a SWT/Jface application, how to properly display exceptions to the user ? I use log4j to log the exceptions, but I need to display the message to the user.

Maybe I could use the same message box as in Eclipse ? But I don't know how to use it.

The thing is : if more than one Exception occured, I want to list all exceptions in one unique message box so that the user need only to click once to close the box.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into the code give me a clue to what I want :

the classes *org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner* and *org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable* are good starting point to understand how exceptions are handled by swt/jface.

It could be use like that :

```
    SafeRunner.run(new ISafeRunnable() {
      public void run() throws Exception {
           // code that throws exceptions...
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it exactly like you would in any other GUI Framework:

**Never present exceptions to the user**

OK, in short, handle exceptions inside the appliction, if possible. An exception is not a wrapper for user messages. It is an application internal signal that something went bad and the application can't continue as usual. Message and stacktrace shall help developers or administrators to find and fix the problem.

If there's something, the poor user needs to know (because he can change something, like checking the network connection), create a message, that is understandable by the user (an exception *does not* qualify) and show this one in a message box.

Leave exceptions to the log files and to the people that know how to read them.

---

From another comment, I read your intention: show more details during development phase. So you need different behaviour for development and production code. You want to add some *debug* code that shows more detailed information in case of errors.

Consider implementing an application wide service, that takes messages and presents them to the user. The implementation for production code will *only* present "user friendly" (localized?) message while the implementation for development purposes displays debug information (full error messages) too.

To make this perfect, you could define a custom extension point and add the "debug extensions" to your User Message Service in a separate bundle. So if you don't install that bundle, the user will not get the extended messages.

Comment: I totaly agree with you : the user do not need to know the technical cause of the problem. So I wrapped root exception with my own Exception. Those exception message are unique and user freindly. But if several errors occured I want to display them in one error message box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MessageBox.

```
    
  MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_ERROR);
  messageBox.setMessage("error message");
  int result = messageBox.open();
  ...
```

*"if more than one Exception occured, I want to list all exceptions in one unique message "*

Why you want to show a list of exceptions to users?. Users only need information about the error and a message with the way to avoid or fix it.

Could you post the list of exception you want to pack or give more information?.

Comment: During development, a message box with something like a buton "Show details" with the list of all exceptions could realy help and improve productivity.

Answer (score 0):

I can only support the answers of Andreas_D and yeraycaballero. The user will only be confused if you show him an exception.

Here another example of how to use the SWT message box:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratestheMessageBoxclass.htm

You may also find helpful information in the official Eclipse API documentation:
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/MessageBox.html